# macOS High Sierra 17G2112 vs 17G65

Tags: high-sierra, install, disk-image

I was trying to use
[installinstallmacos.py](https://github.com/munki/macadmin-scripts/blob/master/installinstallmacos.py) to create an installer disk image for High Sierra 10.13.6 (I need an offline installer and downloading from App Store only downloads a ~4MiB stub file with further install most probably requiring an active internet connection).

The above script lists two different variants of High Sierra 10.3.6:

```
ProductID   Version Build   Title
091-53703   10.13.6 17G2112 macOS High Sierra
091-94326   10.13.6 17G65   macOS High Sierra
```

The page [How to find the macOS version number on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201260), in fact lists only `17G65` for High Sierra 10.13.6 and states:

> Below are the versions and builds of each Mac operating system made available from the Mac App Store,

What is the difference between the two?

Comment: 17G2112 is a special build for the new hardware just released.  The 2018 MacBook Pro.

Comment: @Redarm are you aware of any official source? Request, post this as an answer...

Answer (score 1):

17G2112 is a special build for the new hardware just released. The 2018 MacBook Pro.

It's mentioned as shipping OS at [Everymac.com](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i9-2.9-15-mid-2018-true-tone-display-touch-bar-specs.html)

> Pre-Installed MacOS:  X 10.13.6 (17G2112)

17G65 should be used for every other Mac.